# How can i sort array subarrays by one subarray values? (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array like this:

```
array(
    'sortBy' => array(0 => 3,   1 => 2,   2 => 1),
    'other'  => array(0 => 'x', 1 => 'y', 2 => 'z'),
    'xxx'    => array(0 => 3,   1 => 2,   2 => 1),
    ...
)
```

How can I sort contents of subarray *other* by values in *sortBy* ? There's unlimited amount of *other* subarrays inside that one array, but the keys inside these subarrays are always same(e.g. in *sortBy*, *other*, *xxx* the values of key 0 must all be sorted together)

Sorted array would look like this:

```
array(
    'sortBy' => array(0 => 1,   1 => 2,   2 => 3),
    'other'  => array(0 => 'z', 1 => 'y', 2 => 'x'),
    'xxx'    => array(0 => 1,   1 => 2,   3 => 3)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/array_multisort) to good effect.

```
$array = array(
    'sortBy' => array(3,   2,   1),
    'other'  => array('x', 'y', 'z'),
    'xxx'    => array(3,   2,   1),
);

array_multisort($array['sortBy'], SORT_NUMERIC, $array['other'], $array['xxx']);

var_export($array);
```

The above example prints the following:

```
array (
  'sortBy' => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
  ),
  'other' => 
  array (
    0 => 'z',
    1 => 'y',
    2 => 'x',
  ),
  'xxx' => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
  ),
)
```

**Edit**

Since you decided the array's keys could be anything (other than the one definite key: `sortBy`), then `array_multisort()` can still be used albeit called with a more dynamic list of arguments.

```
$array = array( … );

$args = array(&$array['sortBy'], SORT_NUMERIC);
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($key !== 'sortBy') {
        $args[] = &$array[$key];
    }
}
call_user_func_array('array_multisort', $args);
unset($args);

var_export($array);
```

Comment: I cannot call this function like that, because I don't know all the possible keys, only the sortBy key is known, all other keys are random.

Comment: Then use [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) with an appropriate array of arguments (see edit).

Comment: Works without "if ($key !== 'sortBy')", but I'll add it just to be safe :)

Comment: Yes, it would work but it would be doing extra sorting that is not needed.